# MongoDB Capped Collection For Storing SQL Data Repeatedly

Tags: sql, mongodb, capped-collections

I'm querying a SQL database and want to save the query results in a local mongo db repeatedly (e.g. every 30 minutes). The SQL data is not very consistent that is to say that there are many `null` values.

The data which I want to save has this format:

```
{
  "attribute1": value,
  "attribute2": value,
  "hugeArray": [], // 30.000 entries
}
```

The array has around `100MB` and will not get much larger in the future.

Every 30 minutes the sql query will almost give the same result.

I'm a newbie and I don't know whether `patching` and updating the few old values in the `mongodb` is faster than dropping the `collection` and (re-) adding all values.

I do not really care about the order of which the entries are inserted, I will only make one SQL query and store that data in my mongodb database.

I can't make use of documents because of this restriction:

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

Is a `capped collection` a good choice for my circumstances or are there any better solutions and can you reason that?

Comment: Capped collections still have 16MB per document limit.

Comment: @AlexBlex oh you're right, I haven't seen that number in the restrictions of the capped collection, so I got confused. I'm going to store each sql row in a document.

Comment: how many of these documents will you have?  Would it make sense to put the hugeArray in a collection of its own?

Comment: @robjwilkins Do you mean I should store each element in the array in an extra document, in a seperate collection for the array? Then yes it would make sense but I don't know how it effects the performance. The elements in the array do not have a complex data structure and have only primitive data types.

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann yes that is what I was thinking. You could perhaps do a bulk write.  I think it would be fast to write, but worth testing

Comment: @robjwilkins Ty, i will implement it like that and Test the Speed